# Debug output nodejs in Visual Studio Code

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, visual-studio-code

I am running Visual Studio Code on Ubuntu. Debugging a nodejs app works fine after installing mono. But where can I find the output produced by console.log?

Comment: It should open up a terminal window where the `console.log` output will be printed. However, some people have reported a bug where this console window will not open and they don't see any program output.

Comment: That is my problem too. I run ubuntu 15 by the way

Comment: @LoganTegman also my problem. I'm on a Mac, OSX El Capitan

Answer (score 2):

When in the editor, either:

- hit `CMD-Shift-P` then type `Console` and choose `Open New console`

or

- hit `CMD-Shift-C`

a console window will be opened with nodejs `stdout` and `stderr` connected to it